# iOS network activity indicator is not showing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire networking library to make requests.

I am performing several different tasks like.

- Downloading file
- Uploading file
- Post requests

But the network activity indicator is not showing in the status bar for any of the operation.

What can be a **possible reason** for this behavior?

Is that a thing to **worry**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using Alamofire you should be using the companion library: https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator

From their readme, all you need to do is 
`NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.sharedManager.isEnabled = true`

Comment: Isn't that too much to add a whole dependency for such small behavior?

Comment: thats up to you to decide i guess, some people wouldn't use alamofire since NSURLSession is fairly simple. For this case if you are already using AF this dependency is only 1 extra file, I wouldn't see it as a big issue personally

Answer (score 5):

You've to turn on/off network indicator manually, this is not default behaviour. Here is how you do it

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
```

**Swift code**

```
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3.0 compatible code:

```
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

Answer (score 1):

I did what [wattson12 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36979101/5744323) asked me to do **but it didn't work**.

You also need to add the below line as by default start delay for the indicator is 1.

`NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.shared.startDelay = 0`

If what you are querying is very simple and returns the response within 1 seconds then it won't even show up.

Answer (score 0):

You should manually show network activity indicator like,

```
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

and `false` when want to hide. it will not shown by default.

Hope this will help :)